# Using "viewAtColumn" on a NSOutlineView makes it to lose the ability to collapse or expand

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have a view based NSOutlineView with some NSTextFields on one of it's columns.

To be able to edit any of these fields I have to click on them twice..first to select the row then to another click to select the text field itself and be able to edit it's contents.

The requirement was to be able to select the text fields using a single click. So in the outlineview's delegate i implemented the "outlineViewSelectionDidChange" like this:

```
    func outlineViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        let selected:NSInteger = settingsTable.selectedRow
        let selectedRow = settingsTable.viewAtColumn(1, row: selected, makeIfNecessary: false)
        let field = selectedRow.settingTextField as NSTextField
        field.becomeFirstResponder()      
}
```

where settingsTable is an outlet to my NSOutlineView

This works as needed: When I click on any of the text fields inside the OutlineView the current row is selected and the textfield can be edited without the additional click

The problem is that after I clicked on any of the text fields, when I try to expand/collapse the content, I get this error:

```
Row -1 out of row range [0-4] for rowViewAtRow:createIfNeeded:
```

Which is caused by the "viewAtColumn" method.

Is there an alternative to the "viewAtColumn" method or another way to get a specific NSTableCellView view using it's row and column?

Using a cell based NSOutlineView is not possible due to layout requirements outside my control.

Comment: Apple says: "Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not becomeFirstResponder, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke becomeFirstResponder directly."

Comment: If no row is selected, settingsTable.selectedRow is -1.